# Drawing sequence of points with drawContours

Tags: c++, opencv

**I want to draw custom sequence of Points with OpenCV `drawContours` function.**

My code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Point> contour1;
contour1.push_back(cv::Point(100,100));
contour1.push_back(cv::Point(500,500));
contour1.push_back(cv::Point(500,100));
contours.push_back(contour1);
cv::drawContours(testDrawingImage,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),5);
cv::imshow("test",testDrawingImage);
```

**Why in this case triangle is drawn instead of L-shape?**

Of course I know that I could do this with line. But maybe someone figured out how it should be passed to `drawContours` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drawContours()` does exactly what it says it will, it draws a contour enclosed by the points you give it.  A contour is an outline of a closed shape, therefore the `drawContours()` function will give you a closed shape from the points you provide.